# Rust IDE for Linux

Tags: linux, ide, rust

Expected features:

- Integration with the Rust tool chain, i.e., compile and execute from inside IDE.
- Intelligent code complete suggestions.
- Debugger.

Open Source preferable.

Multiplatform support is good to have, but my primary system is Linux (Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 x64).

Answer (score 5):

I suggest [RustDT](http://rustdt.github.io/):

- Integrates with Cargo build, displays build errors in the editor.
- Code completion / Content Assist (using the Racer tool).
- Debugger integration (using GDB).

See updated list features at: https://github.com/RustDT/RustDT/blob/latest/documentation/Features.md#features

Comment: Note that RustDT is no longer maintained, but there is a new active Eclipse IDE for Rust: Corrosion ( https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/corrosion-develop-rust-applications-eclipse-ide ). It's based on the LSP protocol, and it had some involvement from Redhat developers. I haven't tried it myself but I think it essentially has all the features expected from question (including debugging).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest [Atom](https://atom.io/) by Github.
Sublime Text is good too.

Even Vim has plugins too.

An eclipse plugin's there too called Rusty Cage.

Also, try [Racer](https://github.com/phildawes/racer).

Comment: Atom runs a bit sluggish on Ubuntu. Will check out Racer.

Comment: Atom is buggy too. I enjoy Sublime Text more.

Answer (score 2):

Intellij has a Rust plugin. Still a work in progress but the end result should be good knowing JetBrains.

IDE:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux

Rust Plugin:
https://intellij-rust.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio Code on Linux also supports Rust. Probably the best IDE at the moment.

https://code.visualstudio.com/