# Gratis Rust IDE for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, ide, rust

I've recently started learning Rust. Rust is a relatively new language, the first stable release having only been out in May 2015.

I've looked online and for the most part, the only articles I've found said that there aren't any IDEs for Rust yet. Most of them, however, were published a few years ago and may be outdated by now.

I need to find a Rust IDE that runs on Windows 10 (preferably something like NetBeans), which fulfills these basic requirements:

- It must be completely free.
- It must have syntax highlighting.
- It must be able to run code without exiting the IDE.
- It must have an output console.
- It must have a debugger.

Comment: See also: [Rust IDE for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18900/60)

Comment: Do you have problems with using emacs? it runs great on windows and have modes for everithing. If you have not i put an answer specifying how to configure, as you stated "something as netbeans" as a preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is the best IDE and in the case of RUST it also can be a good solution.

If you go to the *Marketplace* or use the *Integrated extension manager* and search for RUST, you will find: [Rust (rls)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust) (Among many others...)

[image: RUST extensions for VS Code]

Rust support is powered by the *Rust Language Server (RLS)*. If you don't have it installed, the extension will install it for you.

The main advantage is that this extension is built and maintained by the RLS team, part of the Rust IDEs and editors team. And it's totally free.

Features:

- code completion
- jump to definition, peek definition, find all references, symbol search
- types and documentation on hover
- code formatting
- refactoring (rename, deglob)
- error squiggles and apply suggestions from errors
- snippets
- build tasks

Answer (score 1):

I really like the [Eclipse Project](https://www.eclipse.org/) - a powerfull IDE with plugins for nearly every language. [And there seems to be one for Rust](https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-corrosion-eclipse-ide-rust), too.