Best IDE or editor for Rust
I'm beginning to write Rust code (mainly for my Bachelor project) so I was wondering what should I use to write it. Using Windows by the way. Options I found are:

Visual Studio Code
Intellij IDEA Ultimate with Rust plugin
RustRover

As far as I know, RustRover is just Intellij IDEA with Rust plugin and stripped of unnecessary things needed for Rust development.
Main things I'm looking for are:

As much hints as possible (for refactoring, potential errors, not needed code etc.)
Showing docs on hover, for example for some method, struct etc.
Easy imports refactoring
Not really in need of debugger
Easy crate managing (coming from Maven background so I'm used to easy managing packages with Intellij IDEA)
It would be nice for it to be lightweight, although I guess only VS Code is lightweight here


Here you have another post that can be what you're looking for:
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/54085/gratis-rust-ide-for-windows/56175#56175

Thanks. I've already seen that post, but it's 5 years old so I wanted to renew question since, I guess, a lot has changed (I mainly mean on RustRover).

It sounds like Visual Studio Code with rust-analyzer extension is exactly what you're looking for.
However, I would advise you to use VSCodium instead of VSCode, because it doesn't contain Microsoft's telemetry and other bloat (but is the same otherwise).
